# Passing array unsigned in a function recursion in C

Tags: c

How do I use array as argument in recursion?

The procedure

```
void divide(int arr[], int i, int j, int max, int min){
//Deklarasi
int min1, min2, max1, max2, k;//Algoritma
//1 Elemen
if(i == j){
    min = arr[i];
    max = arr[i];
}
else{
    //2 Elemen
    if(i == j-1){
        if (arr[i] > arr[j]){
            max = arr[i];
            min = arr[j];
        }
        else{
            max = arr[j];
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    //>2 Elemen
    else{
        k = (i+j)/2;
        divide(arr[j],i,k,max1,min1);
        divide(arr[j],k+1,j,max2,min2);
        min = (min1>min2) ? (min2) : (min1);
        max = (max1>max2) ? (max1) : (max2);
    }
}
}
```

The main

```
int main(){
int i,j,min,max,x;
i = 1;
scanf("%d",&j);

//Input the array
int arr[j];
for(x=0;x<j;x++){
    scanf("%d",&arr[x]);
}
divide(arr[j],i,j,max,min);
printf("%d %d", min, max);
}
```

when I execute the code, I can input the size and the array, but the program can't run(error)

Please help me, how do I pass array in a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `divide`, you need to pass `arr`, not `arr[j]`. `arr[j]` is just a single element of the array. Also you may want to pass in your min and max as pointers so that you actually get the new values in your main function.